# Enforce Constant in a Class

Tags: php, php-5.4

How can I enforce constants in sub classes?

For example:

```
Class A implements B
{

}

Class B implements I
{

}


interface I
{

const bb = 'lr';

public function aa();

}
```

Above code ensures class `A` & `B` Must have `aa()`, but is there any way I can ensure class `A` & `B` must have a constant `bb`?

Comment: You can't implement class B. You can extend another class only

Answer (score 0):

class A must "extend" (not "implement") B, since B is a class, not an interface.

class B must implement function aa (because you're implementing an interface that implicitly needs all of its functions to be implemented);

Other than that, both A and B have their bb const defined and can be accessed with A::bb and B::bb